# Implement a queue in python that supports undo feature

Tags: python, queue

I've been asked to create a queue in python that has these 3 commands:

- enqueue
- pop
- undo

The undo command will undo the previous enqueue or pop command.

Here's what I've written:
It takes the number of commands and then the commands themselves.
I used the second queue to store the previous state of the first queue.

```
from collections import deque

queue_1 = deque()
queue_2 = deque()
num_of_commands = int(input())
commands = []
for i in range(num_of_commands):
    commands.append(input())

for i in range(len(commands)):
    queue_2 = queue_1.copy()
    if 'enqueue' in commands[i]:
        queue_1.append(int((commands[i].split())[1]))
    elif 'pop' in commands[i]:
        if len(queue_1) != 0:
            print(queue_1.popleft())
    if i < len(commands) - 1:
        if ((commands[i + 1].split())[0]) == 'undo':
            queue_1 = queue_2.copy()
```

Example input:

```
10
enqueue 1
enqueue 2
pop
undo
pop
enqueue 3
undo
pop
enqueue 10
pop
```

Example output:

```
1
1
2
10
```

But my problem is that this doesn't support consecutive undo commands. How can I change it to support multiple consecutive undo commands?

Comment: If your "undo" command really does what you say it does, the expected output should actually be empty, given your sample input.

Comment: I think you'll need to save your commands and not a copy of the list.
I am in no way an expert on this but I would use a directed graph to solve this. Each command being a node, to undo you'll just have to move upwards.

Comment: At first guess I’d say you need to keep track of the last ‘action’ performed each time a new one is done. And if the action was a pop, you’d need to remember what was removed too.

Comment: @blhsing I don't understand what you mean. It shouldn't be empty. First I pop 1 from queue then I undo so 1 is still in the queue and then I pop 1 again so only 2 is in the queue. Then I enqueue 3 and then undo so 2 is in the queue and when I pop, 2 is in the output and so on. This input and output example is in the question context so It's true.

Comment: I see. I did not realize that you mean to produce output when you pop. I thought the expected output reflects the final state of the queue.

Answer (score 1):

Important question here, if you need to have "undoable undo"? )

In any case, I highly recommend encapsulating logic into single class, it's easy to get lost with logic while you're manipulating loose objects.

Lets assume you don't need to undo undos, a little bit sketchy implementation:

```
class QueueWithUndo:
    def __init__(self, history=10):
        self.q = deque()
        self.undo_q = deque(maxlen=history)

    def enqueue(self, task):
        self.undo_q.append((self.q.pop, ))
        self.q.append(task)

    def pop(self):
        result = self.q.popleft()
        self.undo_q.append((self.q.append, result))
        return result

    def undo(self):
        op, *task = self.undo_q.pop()
        op(*task)
```

Idea is simple — 1 deque for tasks, 1 size-restricted (or not) deque that keeps tracking on how to "undo" operations. Normal task deque is used as FIFO queue — so you append on one side, pop from opposite. Undo deque is used as LIFO/stack — last context is what used to undo things.

The tricky thing is that normal and unto queues are inverted every operation, *as well* as arguments. I.e. you need to keep context for pop undo.

Comment: The problem is that the code is checked online by a computer not a human and when I run the code online, it only passes 2 out of 10 test cases and fails the other. The only problem with my code or yours is that they don't support "undoable undo" so I think "undoable undo" is needed.

Comment: Its actually near-impossible to help you, if there's no requirements/info on what you've tried. If you need "undo undo", you need to extend `undo` method with calls to undo queue and manage "swapping" operations